# The provider did not return a ProviderManifest instance Error with Oracle 12c

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, oracle11g, oracle12c, edmx

I have installed oracle 12c client in Windows server 2012. My asp.net mvc4 application uses Oracle 11g database with Entity Framework.

I am getting the following error when I build the solution in Visual Studio 2012:

Inner Exception : **{"ProviderManifestToken is invalid"}**

**The provider did not return a ProviderManifest instance.**

An exception of type '**System.Data.ProviderIncompatibleException**' occurred in **System.Data.Entity.dll** but was not handled in user code

```
<edmx:StorageModels>
<Schema Namespace="Model.Store" Alias="Self" Provider="Oracle.DataAccess.Client" ProviderManifestToken="11g" xmlns:store="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/12/edm/EntityStoreSchemaGenerator" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2009/02/edm/ssdl">
    <EntityContainer Name="ModelStoreContainer">
```

Please help me to resolve this error.

Thanks in Advance

[EDMX source](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0IZte.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just replaced the "11g" with "12.1" which is a Oracle 12c Release 1 so it is 12.1 `ProviderManifestToken="12.1"`, it works for me.